# Scrolling makes VMware Player leave fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I am using the VMware Player which comes with Workstation 8 to run Mac OS X Lion for which I don't have trackpad drivers. Therefore, scrolling doesn't work, which is a pity but not my issue here (I do have VMware tools).

The trackpad is "Synaptics TouchPad V7.5 on PS/2 Port" and my host OS is Windows 7.

When I accidentally scroll inside the Player (having it always fullscreen), it exits the fullscreen (as if I hit ctrl-alt).

The problem is, I can't (don't want to) disable the scrolling, since I am using a multi-monitor setup or switching from one OS to another and I want to be able to scroll in Windows.

I see this as an issue with VMware Player, does anybody know how to fix this?

(I am aware that this is not a "legal" setup and I did purchase a copy of Lion)